# Why the following code results in error?

Tags: python

It works for `Employee` and `calculate_wage`, but returns an error when I try to create an instance of `PartTimeEmployee` and call to the `calculate_wage` method of `PartTimeEmployee`'s parent class.

```
class Employee(object):
     """Models real-life employees!"""
     def __init__(self, employee_name):
         self.employee_name = employee_name

     def calculate_wage(self, hours):
         self.hours = hours
         return hours * 20.00

 class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
     def __init__(self, employee_name):
         self.employee_name = employee_name
     def calculate_wage(self, hours):
         self.hours = hours
         return hours * 12.00
     def full_time_wage(self, hours):
         return super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(self, hours)

 milton = PartTimeEmployee("Milton")
 print (milton.full_time_wage(10))
```

Comment: "but returns error"... alas, the error message seems to be a secret....

Comment: Can you please select my answer to be correct?

Answer (score 5):

```
return super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(self, hours)
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
return super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(hours)
```

And next time: Also post the error message you're seeing.

Comment: Why isn't 'self' required? It is defined in Employee class as calculate_wage(self, hours), I thought I should copy-paste it.

Comment: Because `self` is derived from what's in front of the method call (`self` is set to `foo` when you're doing `foo.calculate_wage(hours)`)

Comment: Can you please, if it is the case, mark my answer to be correct?